# Libgdx - Strange behaviour of sprites while moving app window

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make my first libgdx application basing on book "Learning LibGDX Game Development". Although I follow all instructions provided by author I came across a strange bug. When I move a game window, all of my moving sprites are suddenly falling into the ground (just like collision system stop working) and Player character is being thrown at the top of the level. I have noticed that sometimes this happens even when I enter mouse cursor into an application window. It seems like any kind of action might interrupt game loop. And this is probably why it is hard to localize and fix this bug. Sorry for not pasting any code but frankly I'm not sure what might be causing this issue. I hope maybe some of you had struggled with something like this before? Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
Based on response from @Tenfour04 I have fixed this "tunneling" issue. Here is a code

```
//Main rendering game class
public class GameScreen extends Screen {

     /* 
         some stuff
    */ 

    @Override
    public void render(float deltaTime) {
        float delta = Math.min(1/60f, deltaTime);
        if (!paused) {
            worldController.update(delta);
            //all of the moving actions are being called in this method
        }
        // Sets the clear screen color 
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(174 / 255.0f, 222 / 255.0f, 203 / 255.0f, 255 / 255.0f);
        // Clears the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        worldRenderer.render();
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume you are working with Desktop. Did you resize your window? Or did you use Box2d for physic world?

Comment: When you use delta time you should really limit its value like: float delta = Math.max(1/30f, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); Otherwise, when your game resumes from something like dragging the window, the delta time will be very big, so big that your objects can pass through stuff because they are leaping to the other side. The delta limit is based on how detailed you need to prevent this in your simulation. The problem is called "tunnelling".

Comment: Thank you @Tenfour04 I have added edit based on your response. I'm not sure why but this still not working for me

Comment: Ok, I was too stupid to acknowledge that I actually should take minimum of those two numbers and not maximum. Now everything works great. Thanks !